# Wordpress Gutenberg: Attribute overwritten by block duplicate

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

For a custom wordpress gutenberg block I've created a list of buttons so that users can add/remove as many as needed. While this works pretty fine one issue occurs: When duplicating a block the duplicate overwrites the array values of the origin block as long as we are in editing mode. After saving and refreshing the page the array values become independent. Is anyone aware of that behaviour?

```js
// Simplified code:

// Attributes definition:
...
attributes: {
  buttons: {
    type: 'array',
    default: []
  }
}
...
const buttons = props.attributes.buttons
...
// Edit inspector controls:
buttons.length > 0 && buttons.map( function( button, index ) {
  return el(
    TextControl,
    {
      label: 'Text',
      value: button.text,
      onChange: function( newText ) {
        let newButtons = [ ...buttons ]
        newButtons[ index ][ 'text' ] = newText

        props.setAttributes( { buttons: newButtons } )
      }
    }
  )
}

// Edit / Save output:    
buttons.length > 0 && buttons.map( function( button, index ) {
  return el(
    'a',
    {
      key: 'button-' + index        
    },
    button.text
  )
} )
```

Comment: Hi, 
unfortunately, I get the same problem. I read a lot of GitHub discussions regarding this issue, but no topic leads to solution. There are different proposal to change the core, but none was merged. This is very interesting, because I get the problems only when making duplicate. When making copy/paste then everything is OK. The same as you wrote, when making duplicate, save, and reload the page, then everything is OK (then the array is independent for each block instance)